# Need client javascript function to check digit from textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

On client button click event, I need one javascript function to check whether input value is all in digit (0 to 9) or not. In addition, one more criteria is on radio button option. 
If user choose YES, then allow digit input only. If NO, any characters input.

I found some post which are checking for numeric and which allow decimal point, but for me, I don't allow them to key in decimal or dash or whatever.

Valid character must be digit which is 0 to 9 and count must be 10 (which i can check the length).

```
Example of txtInput.Text
1234567890 -- return true
9781234567 -- return true
12.4567890 -- return false
123-567890 -- return false
123456789X -- return false
```

```
Code:
        function CheckFormInput() {
            var x = document.getElementById("<%#txtInput.ClientID%>").value;
            if (x != "") {
                if (document.getElementById("<%#rbtnYes.ClientID%>").checked) {
                    if (CheckInput(x)) return true;
                    else {
                        alert("Invalid Input!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else {
                alert("Blank not allowed!");
                return false;
            }
        }

        function CheckInput(input) {
            //function to check length 10 & all chars in digit (0 to 9, no space, no dash, no decimal)
            if (document.getElementById("<%#rbtnYes.ClientID%>").checked) {
                if (input.length == 10) {
                // *** continue to check all in digit ***
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

html:-
<asp:Button ID="btnAddFile" runat="server" Text="Add Files" OnClientClick="return CheckFormInput()"  OnClick="btnAddFile_Click" />
```

Appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would be simple to do using a single Regular expression. Google should elicit the exact command(s) you need.

Comment: @Amy, That would be using the pattern attribute... but you can implement regex on a javascript function called from the button onclick. You can also submit the form from javascript. Is that what you want?

Comment: Can you show any code example yet? (not the current example that has no real logic)

Comment: Hi there, sorry for confusion. I've rephrase my question. Hopefully, better now.

Comment: Try regex: `input.match(/^\d{10}/));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( /^\d+$/.test(val) && val.length == 10){

alert("digits only, 10 chars long");

}
```

or

```
 if(!isNaN(parseInt(val)) && val.length == 10){
alert("digits only, 10 chars long");
}
```

html:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10">
```

Comment: This answer doesn't prevent values less than 10 digits long

Comment: @jasonscript sorry :) there it is!

Comment: Hi, dllhell. I used the first code & it's work. Thanks for your time. Have a nice week!

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
  <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{10}">
```

Comment: I need to trigger the checking function upon button click & choice of radio button as well.